# Opening and reading a file of names converting to usernames and storing in another file

Tags: python, file, batch-processing

Foundation year programming student here. I'm trying to do some batch mode processing, Taking a list of names in a file, opening said file, reading it, assigning a username each name in the file and then storing said names in another file.

Here is my code:

```
# A program which takes a list of names from a file, creates a new file
# and makes a username based on each name into it.

#first open each file
import string

def main():
    infileName = raw_input("What file are the names in")
    outfileName = raw_input("What file are the usernames going in?")

    #open the files

    infile = open(infileName, "r")
    outfile = open(outfileName, "w")

    data = infile.read()

    print data


main()   
#process each line in the file
for line in infile:
    #get the first and last names from line
    first, last = string.split(line)
    #create a username
    uname = string.lower(first[0]+last[:7])
    #write it to output file
    outfile.write(uname+"\n")
    #close both files
infile.close()
outfile.close()

print "The usernames have been written to, ", outfileName
```

It all seems fine except it comes out with the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Manol/OneDrive/Documents/Uni/Programming/File Processing File/BatchUsernames.py", line 23, in <module>
    for line in infile:
NameError: name 'infile' is not defined
>>>
```

I don't understand as I thought I had defined it on line 13

```
 infile = open(infileName, "r")
```

If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong it would be much appreciated.
Thanks for you time

- Manos

Answer (score 0):

You defined  it in your `main()` function, so it is a local variable. Any function outside of `main()` won't recognize it. You should probably also use `data` instead but again, that is a local variable. A possible solution could be something like this:

```
import string

def main():
    infileName = raw_input("What file are the names in")
    outfileName = raw_input("What file are the usernames going in?")

    #open the files

    infile = open(infileName, "r")
    outfile = open(outfileName, "w")

    data = infile.read()
    
    for line in data:
        first, last = string.split(line)
        
        uname = string.lower(first[0]+last[:7])
    
        outfile.write(uname+"\n")

    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

    print(data)
    print("The usernames have been written to, ", outfileName)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is much appreciated!